# Как отправить данные json, если кодировка 1251?

Tags: jquery, json, javascript, ajax, php

пересылаю данные(кирилица) через $.ajax на сервер приходит С„С‹РІР°Р°РІ.
Поменять кодировку на utf нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iconv()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.iconv.html) вам в помощь

Comment: нет, не помогает. привидите простой пример, если у вас получаеться.

Comment: .

    $str =  'С„С‹РІР°Р°РІ';
    echo iconv('utf-8','cp1251',$str); // фываав

Answer (score 0):

AJAX

```
                contentType: "application/json; charset=windows-1251",
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: requestData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

PHP

```
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=windows-1251');
```

Так не пробывал?